# How long will an unused hard drive store its memory?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, data-recovery, redundancy, persistence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much time until an unused hard drive loses its data?](https://superuser.com/questions/284427/how-much-time-until-an-unused-hard-drive-loses-its-data)

I have a broken laptop, and it's the motherboards fault that it can't turn its power on.

The laptop has been stored for almost 2 years now and I'm about to get its hard drive (hoping it will still work).

Can I still recover the data in there? How long will the data in the hard drive still attached in the laptop will store its data?