# Does a partition still exist after the HD is unused for a long period of time?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, partitioning

I relation to my previous question here [How long will an unused hard drive store its memory?](https://superuser.com/questions/312669/how-long-will-an-unused-hard-drive-store-its-memory/312764#312764) , I have partitioned the HD twice is there any chance that when I open the HD (as an external drive), the partitioned still exist and the data is still stored? Or let's just pretend that It has the data, will the partition still exist?

Comment: Yes? The partition guides and information is data on the drive interpreted by the computer. So as long as the data is intact and no changes have been made, the partition should be intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your other question, whatever was on the drive, including any partitions, will still be there. Even if the partitions were deleted, unless you secure wiped them, data recovery software would mostly likely be able to pull the data.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is still intact then any partitioning done on the drive should also be intact.