# Is DVDs safe to store data for future?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, dvd, storage

I've started collecting movies, which is the safest way to store the collected movies? Is it safe to store in DVDs or what should I prefer??

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/questions/374609/what-medium-should-be-used-for-long-term-high-volume-data-storage-archival http://superuser.com/questions/374386/how-to-store-and-preserve-lots-of-data

Comment: Commercially mastered DVDs are probably safer than tape.  But writeable DVDs are not at all trustworthy.  And there's always the problem of finding a device to read the media 20 years hence.  In many ways good quality safety film, stored in a well-controlled environment, is the safest.

Comment: The best DVD+R media (Verbatim AZO, for instance) should last 70 years. Commercially pressed disks should last longer - I think I read a claim once that they'd be readable in more than a thousand years. The vast majority of DVD-R and DVD+R media (including seemingly good brands) aren't as long lasting, and cheap DVD-Rs can be useless within days of burning. DVD+R is supposed to have an advantage over DVD-R in terms of error correction - some data on DVD-R not being correctible at all - but I don't know if that claim is accurate.

Comment: With good quality DVDs, the bigger issue will be finding drives that still work, connecting it to available machines when SATA and USB have been obsolete for decades, and finding drivers that will work with Windows 17 or whatever. But the same issue applies with hard drives and any other media.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about commercially pressed discs, keeping them in a dark, temperature and humidity controlled environment should keep them safe for quite a few years. Don't forget to keep a player and TV handy. Who knows what devices and connectors will be available in the future.

However, data archival in general is a complex topic. You're not just talking about media reliability, but also format readability. Among other things.,