# How to store personal data locally (non-cloud solutions)?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, power-supply, local-storage, data-loss-prevention

As the title pretty much summarises, storing data in External HDD (especially the ones which require power supply) is not exactly a risk-free solution. I have burnt my hands more than once even with much reputed brands in the market. There are a wide range of issues like the HD going undetected, cannot be mounted or partition table, bad sector, wow!

I currently have all my data finally cornered to a 4TB external HD (with external power) at the risk of extinction. What are recommended ways for saving huge data locally without worrying about losing it. Is it that inevitable at all.

Thanks in advance.

PS: DvD/BluRayDs is one option for the worst case. Looking for some others too if any.

Comment: VTC as too broad. There are many choices (you've even suggested a couple); just pick one, and if you have a problem while implementing it, come back here with that problem.

Comment: Any solution has inherent risks. The question you need to ask is, of the possible causes of data loss what are the most probable? Avoid those and stop flagellating yourself over it. Many enterprises and end users use portable external drives for backups with low risk of data loss and with low incidence of the issues you made mention of. If you're worried about your current external drive dying or having some other issue then back that up to another drive. I backup my data to two different external drives and I'm comfortable and confident that that's enough for me.

Comment: Relevant, if not duplicate (in sight of the apparent fear of loss) of [What medium should be used for long term, high volume, data storage (archival)?](http://superuser.com/q/374609/228536)

Comment: Along with the question it references: [How to store and preserve lots of data?](http://superuser.com/questions/374386/how-to-store-and-preserve-lots-of-data)

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining a local backup is not very difficult and is very achievable with little effort.

**What you will need:**

- 2-3 4TB external hard drives
- Software [RAID 1 (Mirror explained)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/raid-levels-tutorial/) capabilities from Windows 7/8
- If no RAID then [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155)

**What you can do:**

- Plug in 2 drives and set up [Windows RAID 1 (Mirror)](http://www.buildegg.com/bewp/?p=44)

or

- Plug in 2-3 drives
- Declare a "Master" drive which you interact with (add/copy/delete files to and from)
- Set up SyncToy to do a daisy-chained **echo** process from Master->Slave->Slave
- The echo option will mimic all adds/updates/deletes made to the Master drive