# HDD maintanance. minimal power on of external hard drive (for backup)

Tags: external-hard-drive, maintenance, backup, lifespan, physical-wear

I want to use a external hard drive (not ssd) for backup. however I have heard that because of the mechanical nature of a HDD, it needs to be powered on and spin regularly to maximize its lifespan.

The question is: *If I want to optimise the lifespan of the drive, what is the longest time I can leave it turned off and still keep it "healthy"*

I plan to keep off site, and visit it every 6 month. But fear that is to long.

**EDIT**

@karen pointed to some very good information. -thanks

In [how-much-time-until-an-unused-hard-drive-loses-its-data](https://superuser.com/questions/284427/how-much-time-until-an-unused-hard-drive-loses-its-data) the minimal recomendation for is

> Depending on the priority of the data you've stored, you may want to refresh the hard disk more often. If it is essential data, I would recommend no less then 2 years at maximum. If you can withstand some chance of minor data loss (e.g. a few corrupted sectors here and there), go with 5 years.

This is nice to know and show that my 6 month revisit plan is fine. However I am wondering what would be best frequency to optimise the drives lifespan.

Comment: Where did you hear this exactly?  A mechanical drive doesn't need to be powered in order to keep stored data.

Comment: @Ramhound. it is not to store the data, but to keep the mechanical parts from  being entrenched. I read it some where on SE, but cant find it. e.g. if you leave a HDD for a couple of years it will most likely fail.

Comment: Unless I can read it, I can't tell if what you read, is about of non-sense or not.  I have never heard of it in my 10 years of working with computers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much time until an unused hard drive loses its data?](http://superuser.com/questions/284427/how-much-time-until-an-unused-hard-drive-loses-its-data), [Will desktop and hard drives stored for 7 years still work?](http://superuser.com/questions/912078/will-desktop-and-hard-drives-stored-for-7-years-still-work) and others. Also see [Does an unplugged hard drive used for data archival deteriorate?](http://serverfault.com/questions/51851/does-an-unplugged-hard-drive-used-for-data-archival-deteriorate)

Comment: @Karan: based on the comments, the proposed duplicate (and third suggestion) aren't relevant, but your second suggestion looks like a match.  I'm proposing that as a duplicate.