# Do Hard Disks Really Have Lifespan of only 10 years?

Tags: hard-drive

I read [online](https://www.google.com/search?q=hard+disk+lifespan&oq=hard+disk+lif&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0i512l7j0i390.9701j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on various websites that hard disks only live for 3-5 years, at max 10 years.

I have been taking backups in one Seagate 2TB hard disk for 5 years now. Does this mean I may lose my data because the disk may die anytime soon?

What are my other alternatives? Do I keep buying a hard disk every few years to keep my data safe?

I do not like storing my data on cloud due to latency issues. I prefer access to data directly when I need it.

Comment: Related : https://superuser.com/questions/284427/how-much-time-until-an-unused-hard-drive-loses-its-data

Comment: Those are purely averages... I have seen hard drives die in a few years or less, and I still have some from the 90''s, and even the late 80's, that still work as expected. That said, backups are incredibly important, if you only have one backup then you don't really have one... The general rule for system admins is NUMBER OF BACKUPS=BACKUPS-1

Comment: agree @acejavelin, I got 10 out of an outdoor storage building recently with no climate control, been in there for 20 years, all of them worked and could read all data.